# Google Mock: is there a way to avoid RetireOnSaturation for ordered expectations?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googlemock

I'm using `StrictMock`'s and `InSequence` expectations like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, handleMessage(_)).Times(AnyNumber());        // expectation #1

{
    InSequence s;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, handleMessage(_));                // expectation #2
}
```

The desired effect would be to allow for a single `handleMessage()` call. But, expectation #2 is automatically retired after one call and additional calls are possible by virtue of expectation #1. Note that I would like, if possible, to keep expectation #1 in a default section because by default, the function must be allowed, but for one specific test, must be limited to one call. The documentation says that `InSequence` calls retire automatically. Is there a way to prevent this? I also need `InSequence` because I have lots of other expectations near expectation #2.

What I tried: inserting a `EXPECT_CALL(mock, handleMessage(_)).Times(0);` just before expectation #2 doesn't help -- it seems to have no effect presumably because, being in a sequence, it's satisfied and retired on the fly.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to define a default expectation allowing any number of `handleMessage()` calls and for a single test limit the number of allowed calls to 1.
If you use a `NiceMock<YourMockType> mock;` you don't have to write `EXPECT_CALL(mock, handleMessage(_)).Times(AnyNumber());` in all tests not caring about the number of calls.
In the test with a single call you can use a `StrictMock<YourMockType> mock;` combined with `EXPECT_CALL(mock, handleMessage(_));`.
Would that do the trick?

Comment: It would if things were this simple, BUT, the problem is I would like my mock to be "nice" when it comes to some methods and "strict" when it comes to others. I'd like to use a StrictMock, then in the mock c-tor specifically allow some methods to be called any number of times, then in some tests, refine that, and allow e.g. only one call.